# Json API -> Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json, object, decode

I have read lots of different articles on this but can't seem to find a solution that works.

I'm currently working on getting json data from an API (I have to authorize the connection first) and outputting data from it. (only bits and pieces, like name, id, etc., not the whole thing)

First of all, let me show you my code:

```
class Connector {
//authorization to the API
public $token;
private $username = 'myuser';
private $password = 'mypassword';

public function __construct() {
    $this->getToken();
    setcookie ('token', $this->token, time() + 3600, 'https://mycloud.com');
}

public function getToken() {
    $url = 'https://auth.mycloud.ch/sso2.php';

    $fields = array(
        'username' => $this->username,
        'password' => $this->password
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $this->token = json_decode($result, true)['token'];

    curl_close($ch);
}


public function getData($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'token=' . $this->token);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result->{'id'};

    //print_r($result);


}
}


$cnt = new Connector();
$cnt->getData('https://hr.mycloud.ch/services/api/employee/10');
```

For some reason it can't output the data when I do echo $result->{'id'}; 
It tells me "Trying to get property of non-object"
But I already used json_decode on it...
`$this->token = json_decode($result, true)['token'];`

When I do print_r($result);  it gives me this array:

```
 [{"id":"10","name":"name","employee_id":"id@test.com","user_settings_id":"0","location_id":"1","company_id":"1","active":"1","employee_type":"type_ch"}]
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I have also tried it with a foreach loop but it gave me the same error.
 I hope you can help me with this, thank you.

Comment: EDIT: I have noticed that I haven't decoded the $result in function getData, I just tried it and it still gives me the same error

Comment: See what `json_decode()` returns with `var_dump()`. It's probably an array, not and object.

Comment: Yes, it tells me that it's an array....

Comment: No sorry, I accidentally outputted a different variable.
It retuns an array

Comment: Then @degr's answer should apply here.

Comment: Yes I just tried it and it worked! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's an array of objects

```
$res = json_decode($result);

     foreach($res as $item){
        echo $item->{'id'};
     }
```

or

```
$res[0]->id;
```

Comment: This gives me following error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Thanks, it worked now! Don't know why it said it was an invalid argument before.

Comment: And also, as usual, I use json_decode($result, true); In this case all your object will be interpreted as assoc arrays.

Comment: `Don't know why it said it was an invalid argument before.` because foreach expects to become an array as the first parameter, you tried to pass a string ;)

Comment: When I apply true it gives me the non object error again :P

Comment: @Florian yeah I figured it out now that I've seen what variable I tried to use as a parameter

Comment: @jerryp177: `When I apply true it gives me the non object error again :P` because it returns an array of array then, no array of object ;) And you can not use an array as an object and no object as an array.

Comment: of cause it will trigger non - object error, because it's an array. In array case you need to do $res[0]['id']

Comment: Yes sorry, got kind of confused there. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't use json_decode on your returned string from curl and you doesn't get an object, you get a array of objects, use:

```
<?php
public function getData($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'token=' . $this->token);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $res = json_decode($result);

    curl_close($ch);

    // sidenote: Always check, if json_decode was successful, it can return false on failure
    if ( $res !== null ) {
        // you get an array of objects, not an object, see your json input
        echo $result[0]->{'id'};
    }

    //print_r($result);
}
```

Note: You should check, if `json_decode` returns `null` or not (null is the return value on failure).